# Federal Reserve shapefile for map

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5

I would like to create my own custom version of this map http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=130706717, however i do not know where to get the correct shapefile to create the map.

I understand paths in flex 4 thanks to this article http://brambley.tumblr.com/post/342198004/interactive-flex-maps-with-flash-builder-4-and-fxg, however I am stumped as to where to get the actual map for the federal reserve beige book. Please help!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a mapping component, I'd propose [ModestMaps](http://modestmaps.com/).

Used it recently. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question as I was looking for the same shapefile, if it existed, for my work. For others who are looking for a shapefile so that they could do more than visualize: Right now you have to use a raster map of districts (like that at [Wiki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Federal_Reserve_Districts_Map.svg)) and cross-reference with shapefiles of counties/states at a national level (pulling from TIGER files at Census.gov for example). It will only get hairy on the mid-central and SE sides. Using QGIS or ArcGIS is easiest to make the assignments and export as a shapefile, also could use PostGres with POSTGIS and a viewer like OpenJump. I'll eventually combine these pieces and post a shapefile publicly.